# Can this code be improved?

Tags: apex, trigger

the below trigger code compare the old and new value and based on the it subtract or add to the used_qty and its working as expected but I'm not really sure if this code can be re-write better than what it is?

the only place I'm not sure if I'm following the best practice is this code snippet:

```
 if(item.Quantity__c > oldAli.Quantity__c) {
     diffQty = (item.Quantity__c - oldAli.Quantity__c);
     theUpdateUsedValue = (diffQty + existsUsed);
 }
 if(item.Quantity__c < oldAli.Quantity__c) {
       diffQty = (item.Quantity__c - oldAli.Quantity__c); 
       theUpdateUsedValue = (diffQty - existsUsed);
 }
```

Trigger apex code:

```
public static void UpdateUsed(List<asset_line_item__c> alis, Map<Id, asset_line_item__c> oldMap)
{
   Map<Id, asset_line_item__c> mapOld = new Map<Id, asset_line_item__c>();
   for(asset_line_item__c newAli : alis)
   {            
        asset_line_item__c oldAli = oldMap.get(newAli.Id); 
        if(newAli.Quantity__c != oldAli.Quantity__c) {
            setAliIds.add(newAli.Id);
            mapOld.put(oldB.Id, oldB);
        } 
   }

   list<asset_line_item__c> ali_list  [select .... where ali in : setAliIds];

   List<Product2> updateProducts = new List<Product2>();
   for(asset_line_item__c item : ali_list) {
       for (Id key : mapOld.keySet()) {
           Decimal existsUsed = integer.valueOf(item.product__r.Used__c);
           asset_line_item__c oldAli = mapOld.get(key); 
           Decimal diffQty = 0;
           if(ali_list.Id == oldAli.id) {
                 if(item.Quantity__c > oldAli.Quantity__c) {
                    diffQty = (item.Quantity__c - oldAli.Quantity__c);
                    theUpdateUsedValue = (diffQty + existsUsed);
                 }
                 if(item.Quantity__c < oldAli.Quantity__c) {
                    diffQty = (item.Quantity__c - oldAli.Quantity__c); 
                    theUpdateUsedValue = (diffQty - existsUsed);
                 } 
             //DML operation add it to updateProducts...
             Product2 p = new Product2();
             p.Id = b.flower__r.id;
             p.Qty__c = theUpdateUsedValue ;         
             updateProducts.add(p);
           } 
       }    
   } 
   update updateProducts; 
}
```

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that references to variable names like `b.product__r.Id` and `oldB` are just copy/paste errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do all of that with one simple statement:

```
updateProducts.add(
    new Product2(
        Id=b.Flower__c,
        Qty__c=item.product__r.Used__c + (item.Quantity__c - oldAli.Quantity__c)
    )
);
```

This works because adding a negative number is the same as subtracting a positive number, which is basically what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Take the common stuff (the calculation of `diffQty`) out of the `if` blocks to make your code more DRY.

Once you do that, you can also change the conditional inside the if to check if `diffQty` is greater/less than 0 rather than pulling in data from the two object instances multiple times.

Since the two cases are mutually exclusive, you can make the second `if` an `else if` to (sometimes) save a comparison.

Most of those are really just micro-optimizations though, and won't have a noticeable effect on anything.

**+edit:**

The much bigger improvement that you can make is to get rid of that nested for loop

```
List<Product2> updateProducts = new List<Product2>();
for(asset_line_item__c item : ali_list) {
    for (Id key : mapOld.keySet()) {
        <code omitted>
    }
}
```

Most of the point in having a map in the first place is so you don't have to write code like that.

`mapOld` will only contain records from `ali_list`, so that nested for loop iterating over the `mapOld` keyset is pointless (bad, even).

Even making `mapOld` itself is redundant.

Pseudocode for a much improved version looks like this

```
List<Product2> updateProducts = new List<Product2>();
for(asset_line_item__c item : ali_list) {
    // grab the old record from oldMap

    // declare existsUsed and diffQty

    // calculate diffQty

    // if/else if to check if diffQty is positive or negative

    // create your product instance for updating, add to update list
}
```

**+edit 2:**

If you could make a formula field on `Asset_Line_Item__c` to hold the value of `product__r.Used__c`, you could remove even more of that code (you wouldn't need to run the query), and also do all of the work in a single for loop.

The only other thing you are getting from that query is `item.flower__r.Id`, which can be replaced with `item.flower__c` (I assume that the variable `b` is supposed to be `oldAli` or `item`

Comment: Except, once you keep going, you'll realize that you can completely write out about 13-15 lines of code, which does have an appreciable effect on CPU time used.

Comment: @sfdcfox Yep, I realized that, and am in the middle of editing my answer to address it.

Answer (score 0):

I have optimized what i can. here is the code of your business logic and changed objects and fields to check in my org.

```
public class sample {

    public static void updateProduct(List<Account> oldAssetLineItemList, List<Account> newAssetLineItemList) {
        //products to update 
        List<Product2> updateproductList = new List<Product2>();
        List<Id> accountIdList = new List<Id>();        
        for(Account acc : newAssetLineItemList) {
            accountIdList.add(acc.id);
        }
        //this query is used to get reference values (__r)
        Map<Id,Integer> referenceMap = new Map<Id,Integer>();
        for( Account acc : [select Id From Account Where id in :accountIdList] {
            //map for reference value
            referenceMap.put(acc.id,acc.referenceValue);
        }  
        for(Integer index=0;index<oldAssetLineItemList.size();index++) {
            //change to your reference variable
            Decimal existsUsed = referenceMap.get(newAssetLineItemList[index].id);       
            if(oldAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue != newAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue)  {
                Product2 p = new Product2();
                //p.Id = b.flower__r.id;
                //p.Name= newAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue > oldAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue?
                  //  (newAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue- oldAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue) + (existsUsed): 
                  //  (newAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue- oldAssetLineItemList[index].AnnualRevenue) - (existsUsed);
                updateproductList.add(p);                         
            }         
        }    
        update updateproductList;
    }

}
```